# How to forward to same page in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, forward

I have one Menu that have **pageOne** and **pageTwo** working by forward. So i clicked to forward my **pageOne** and thats OK, my forward is done! But if i already stay on **pageOne** and i click **pageOne** again, forward dont happen.

- I work using template on my system.
- I work with *ViewScoped* on **pageOne**, and my **menuBean** is *SessionScoped*.

Follow the struture:

> ```
>           _____________________ 
>    MENU: |  PAGE1   |   PAGE2  |
>           ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
>
>       PAGE ONE SUCESS LOADED HERE
> ```

My menu is biding and i set the pages on Bean:

```
menuPage1.setCommand("pageOne");
```

FacesConfig

```
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>pageOne</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/PageOne.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
```

My wish is reload page again.

im sorry but i dont found nothing look like that in this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with a redirect:

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>pageOne</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/PageOne.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```